# How to define fallback fonts for XTerm

Tags: debian, terminal, fonts, unicode, xterm

I'm on a fresh Debian Buster installation with packages `fonts-noto-core` and `fonts-symbola`. I want to use "Noto Sans Mono" as the main font for XTerm, so I set the following line with `xrdb`:

```
xterm*faceName: Noto Sans Mono
```

That works. Now, if a symbol isn't found in "Noto Sans Mono" ( for example), XTerm automatically uses the one from "Symbola Regular". However, I want XTerm to look for the symbol in "Noto Sans Symbols2 Regular", first - and only if that font also doesn't contain the symbol ( for example), then look in "Symbola Regular".

Comment: [xterm #373](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_373) supports this feature; the question is a few months older than that.